# How to force LEFT OUTER JOIN return NULL or empty?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT table1.id, table2.name
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.id;
```

so if table1.id = NULL I want to return NULL or empty string from table2, i.e.

```
ID,     NAME
1       name1
2       name2
null    null
3       name3
```

but now getting "column ambiguously defined" error since table2 has many NULLs in ID column

Comment: This query should not be raising that error. Are you sure that's the code you are running?

Comment: you get this error ORA-00918 column ambiguously defined. when  a column is used in a join exists in more than one table and is referred with out the table alias, we don't see that in your example query , unless the query that gave you the error is different than the one shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does return what you want, without any errors:

```sql
SELECT table1.id, table2.name
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.id;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 ( id ) AS
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table2 ( id, name ) AS
SELECT 1, 'name1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'name2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'name3' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
>   ID | NAME 
> ---: | :----
>    1 | name1
>    2 | name2
>    3 | name3
> null | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1a4c2652c35d5156855baa7595ffeb6a)*